# Possible to make a transparent gradient mask?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mask

i have different images in a uiscrollview and i want to know if it´s possible to create an mask-overlay from from 100% - 50% - 0% transparency, so i get smooth fades when the images are moving out.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a gradient at the edges of the scroll view to "feather" the edges of images?

Comment: I´ve created an alpha-mask in photoshop and positioned that over my scrollview. The backgroundcolor has the same color as the gradient of my overly of the end of both image-ends. So it works - buts thats a workaround". Therefore i would like to know if its a alpha-gradient function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do you can simply create an overlay view that is black and change it's alpha to 0 and animate the change.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.65];

    overlayView.alpha = 0.0; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Or you could use CATransition, where something like this should do it:

```
// First create a CATransition object to describe the transition
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
// using the ease in/out timing function
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

[[self.view layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:@"slideShowOptionsFadeIn"];
```